# PHP Notice: Undefined index / PHP Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php

I am really getting frustrated. I am moving my website from php 5.2 to php 5.3. When adding information from my form to the mysql database an empty record is added and I am getting this error messages, which are connected to each other. The error log message is:

```
[Tue Jul 16 12:37:08 2013] [warn] [client XX.XX.XXX.XXXX] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: prijs in XXX/page.php on line 100, referer: XXX/page.php
[Tue Jul 16 12:37:08 2013] [warn] [client XX.XX.XXX.XXXX] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:      Undefined index: type_contract in XXX/page.php on line 116, referer: XXX/page.php
[Tue Jul 16 12:37:08 2013] [warn] [client XX.XX.XXX.XXXX] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: klantnummer in XXX/page.php on line 117, referer: XXX/page.php
[Tue Jul 16 12:37:08 2013] [warn] [client XX.XX.XXX.XXXX] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: datum in XXX/page.php on line 118, referer: XXX/page.php
[Tue Jul 16 12:37:08 2013] [warn] [client XX.XX.XXX.XXXX] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: omschrijving in XXX/page.php on line 119, referer: XXX/page.php
```

I have tried everything, like adding

```
if (isset($_POST['prijs'])) { $prijs = $_POST['prijs']; }
```

The code it is referring to is:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == "abonnement_toevoegen")) {

$prijs = $_POST['prijs'];  <=== this is the code is referring to!!!

$prijs_comma = str_ireplace(",", ".", "$prijs");

$prijs = $prijs_comma;
$btw = $prijs * 0.21;
$totaal = $prijs + $btw;

$prijs = round($prijs, 2);
$btw = round($btw, 2);
$totaal = round($totaal, 2);

$prijs_weergave = str_ireplace(".", ",", "$prijs");
$btw_weergave = str_ireplace(".", ",", "$btw");
$totaal_weergave = str_ireplace(".", ",", "$totaal");

include("include_addslashes.php");

$type_contract = $_POST['type_contract']; <=== this is the code is referring to!!!
$klantnummer = $_POST['klantnummer']; <=== this is the code is referring to!!!
$datum = $_POST['datum']; <=== this is the code is referring to!!!
$omschrijving = $_POST['omschrijving']; <=== this is the code is referring to!!!

$sql = "INSERT INTO wi_abonnementen
(
type_contract,
klant_id,
factuurdatum,
omschrijving,
prijs,
btw,
totaal
 )
VALUES
(
'$type_contract',
'$klantnummer',
'$datum',
'$omschrijving',
'$prijs_weergave',
'$btw_weergave',
'$totaal_weergave'
)";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

include("include_stripslashes.php");
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Please help, I am getting this error message over and over again with different websites.

The HTML code of the form is:

```
<form action="finance.php?action=abonnement_toevoegen" method="post"  name="abonnement_toevoegen">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td><select name="type_contract" size="1">
            <option value="">Kies een optie</option>
            <option value="tco">TouringcarOfferte</option>
            <option value="tao">TaxiOfferte</option>
            <option value="wih">Wi4 Hosting</option>
            <option value="wii">Wi4 Internet diensten</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Klant</td>
    <td><select name="klantnummer" size="1">
            <option value="">Kies een optie</option>
                            <option value=""> ()</option> 
                            <option value="wi126">XXX (wi126)</option> 
                            <option value="Wi154">XXX (Wi154)</option> 
                            <option value="wi108">XXX (wi108)</option>
                        </select>       
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Factuurdatum</td>
    <td><input class="form" type="Text" name="datum" value="2013-07-17" size="10">        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">Omschrijving</td>
    <td><textarea class="form" name="omschrijving" cols="25" rows="4"></textarea>    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Prijs (excl. BTW)</td>
    <td>&#8364; <input class="form" type="Text" name="prijs" value="" size="10">    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="form" value="Voeg toe"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id='abonnement_toevoegen_errorloc' class='error_strings'></div>
</form>
```

Thanx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Do you mean the HTML of the input form?

Comment: I have added the code into the question Deepu

Comment: The other answer did not help me Yogesh Suthar.

Comment: After `<?php if (isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == "abonnement_toevoegen")) {` type `print_r($_POST);` and see what the $_POST array contains.

Comment: I have done it already at the end of the script with a var_dump script. It all looks good: array(5) { ["type_contract"]=> string(3) "tco" ["klantnummer"]=> string(5) "Wi203" ["datum"]=> string(10) "2013-07-17" ["omschrijving"]=> string(4) "test" ["prijs"]=> string(3) "100" }

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that, sorry. Hmm, only thing I can notice is that you don't seem to have closed your first if statement, though that doesn't really seem too relevant.

Comment: No, that's down the code ...

Comment: When posting the form it adds the record, but it adds also another empty line to the mysql database. In php 5.2 it was working all fine, but the migration to php 5.3 bings trouble.

Comment: Oh right, I see. Didn't realise it was actually saving the record first. Do you have anything in your code that might be doing a redirect back to the same page?

Comment: Yes,lots of it. It worked fine in php 5.2. Might the problem be there?

Comment: I posted an answer, hope that helps.

Comment: **SharkofMirkwood**, I found the sollution! Check below.

Comment: No, i did not!!! I thought that I had to give the database fields different names than the records from where i was posting, the form fields, but that does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would've worked in a previous version of PHP but not in a new one.

However, I'm certain the problem is that the whole thing is working fine the first run, then there's a redirect back to the same page, where no `POST` variables are set because it's not coming from a form.

Try getting rid of any redirects, that should fix it. Then sort out the redirecting as needed (though you shouldn't need to redirect again after the form has been submitted).

Feel free to post the rest of your code if you want me to take a look at what else is going on.

Comment: Thanks,I am going to test it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help. I would like to send you the full code, but it I would not have it out on the Internet. Is there a possibility that we can skype, or that I send you the code by e-mail?

Comment: Just upload it to Pastebin.com  and post the link ;)

Comment: Sorry, just realised you didn't want to have it on the internet. Yeah I can contact you via email if you like, can't guarantee a solution though.

Comment: This code is no problem. Can I contact you tomorrow by email / skype? Please send me your number / address?

Comment: Sure, my email address is in my profile. I'm quite busy and at work though, so might not be able to take a look too soon.